# Definite article

Tags: grammar

***Situation 1:**

I am watching a talk show interviewing a dog trainer.
The dog trainer at first introduced himself and he said:

"I am X, a dog trainer, I love dogs, I help **the** dogs living in the streets.

He used "the". As I see, he is talking about dogs- kind of stray dogs living in the streets in general, not specific dogs, so why "the" is used here.

My opinion is that the word “the dogs” are considered specific if he (the speaker) and the listeners know that which dogs he is talking about (for example the tray dogs he has helped so far, or the stray dogs in his neighborhood).

Is it Correct to remove “the” here?

***Situation 2:**

I have searched on this forum and found that this sentence is both correct with and without "the":
So that (1) and (2) are correct to use.

(1)The people in Japan speak Japanese.
(2)People in Japan speak Japanese.

But with this sentence, the same context, but only the version without "the" works, this means only
(4) works:

(3) The stores in Japan are typically open in the evenings.

(4) Stores in Japan are typically open in the evenings.

I don't know the reason, could you please help me?

Comment: The use of **the** is optional in all your examples. The choice might depend on the context,; that's to say, on whatever had preceded the statement.

Comment: @RonaldSole the context in situation (1) I have already provided my question . The context in situation (2) is that I am talking with my friend, and I want to start with a general statement about Japan.

Comment: In that case, 2 is more likely. But1 is perfectly acceptable. As I said, **the** is optional in all your examples.

Comment: @RonaldSole, you said (1) and (2) are both correct to use. How about (3) and (4), these sentences are also correct to use. Right?

Comment: if I want to say something about my job to a friend:

My job is to help (the) dogs living in the streets.

Because I am not referring to specific dogs, so that I should omit “the” here. Right?

Comment: You could think of 'living in the streets' as a phrase describing the particular group of dogs that he works with, or you could think "Of all the dogs in this town, he works with the ones that live on the streets". In practice, there is no difference in meaning.

Comment: @KateBunting does "the dogs living in the streets" refer to dogs in general (over the world), not only the dogs in this town as you said?

Comment: It depends whether the person in question works only in one town or a wider area! "The section of the dog population that live on the streets".