# Definite article “the”

Tags: grammar

If I start a conversation as below. Is it correct to use “the”:

1. I love to help dogs, especially (THE) dogs living on the streets.

Is “the” optional here? And what is the difference between with and without “the”?

Comment: You could also use "those dogs" or if you are refering to some dogs that are present when you speak "these dogs".

Comment: In an sense of generalization (1)" I love (THE) people who love dogs". This sentence also refers to a group of people, as opposed to other kinds of people. A native speaker told me that "the" must be omitted and It is incorrect to use "the" here. But why using "the" in this sentence is considered correct in the sentence in my first post (2)" I love to help (THE) dogs living in the street. "

Comment: Already discussed [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/328053/definite-article).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "the" is optional and it makes no difference to the meaning.
In my opinion "the" may add a slight emphasis to which group of dogs you wish to help, but, in this context, you have already said "especially" so it adds very little weight.

Comment: If I remove the first sentence, and start the conversation like this: “I love to help dogs living on the streets”. Here “the” must be omitted. Right?

Comment: @LEHANH Again, "the" is completely optional. I'd probably leave it out as it is unnecessary, but either way it's grammatically correct. If you wanted to specify a particular dog then you need "the" or "that". *I'd like to help that / the dog over there who is living on the streets.*

Comment: In an sense of generalization (1)" I love (THE) people who love dogs". This sentence also refers to a group of people, as opposed to other kinds of people. A native speaker told me that "the" must be omitted and It is incorrect to use "the" here.  But why using "the" in this sentence is considered correct in the sentence in my first post  (2)" I love to help (THE) dogs living in the street. "

Comment: @LEHANH I'm afraid I would disagree with your friend. I too am a native English speaker and, whilst not necessary, "the" is grammatically correct. In English we are often taught to "keep it simple". That is use as few words as is necessary to convey the correct meaning. So in written English you would almost certainly leave out "the", but in spoken English the occasional "extra" word is natural. There is a similar joke, "Don't use a big word where a diminutive one will suffice".

Comment: If so, If I meet a new friend and introduce: *Hi, my name is X, my job is to help (THE) dog living on the streets. "The" is also optional here. Right?

Comment: @LEHANH In a word - yes.

Comment: @LEHANH I agree with both your friends and Peter Jennings. It's **grammatically correct** to say, "I love **the** people who love dogs", but your friends are right that it's unnatural. We'd never say that. Your question is an excellent one about why "the people who love dogs" is unnatural, but "the dogs living in the street" is natural. I can't think of a good answer.

Comment: @gotube Yes "unnatural" was the word I was looking for, thanks

Comment: If I start the conversation: (1)"I love to help dogs, especially (THE) dogs living on the streets."==>"I love to help dogs", this sentence identify a group of animal (dogs not cats...), then I separate this group of animal to a smaller subgroup, that is "THE" dogs living on the street (not the dogs have an owner). Because there is a subgroup/subset here, I think that use "THE" here is natural. Right? ....

Comment: ...But when I start the conversation like this " “I love to help (THE) dogs living on the streets”.==> There is NO subgroup/subset, I refers to dongs living on the streets in general, so that "THE" here make the sentence sound natural. Right?

Comment: @LEHANH As we keep telling you, "the" is optional in ALL your examples and it is more natural to leave it out.